# How to redirect to another page in my site with PHP code?

Tags: php, variables, redirect, sms, bulksms

This is bulk SMS sending code, and it works good and sends messages, but after sending a message, the web browser redirects me to code in a white page.

I want after sending a message to redirect to another page on my site.

```
$username = '';
    $password = '';
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.xxxx/xx');
    $numbers = 'xxxx ';
    $message = 
    'hi this is a test 
    !@#$%^&*
    ';
    $senderName = 'xxxxxx';
    try {
    $response = $client->sendSMS($username, $password, $numbers, $message, $senderName);
    var_dump($response);
    } catch(SoapFault $exception ) {
    echo $exception->faultcode . ' : ' .$exception->faultstring . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect to a new page using header:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html');
```

Comment: I TRY THQT BUT DONT WORK

Comment: Make sure you put it in your code right after the `$response = $client->sendSMS($username, $password, $numbers, $message, $senderName);
    var_dump($response);`

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/43/11678743/html/click/sms.php:9) in /home/content/43/11678743/html/click/sms.php on line 19

Comment: @hossam365 You obviously have output above one of your files and could be inside one of your included files. Anything above `<?php` is considered as output.

"Anything" could be HTML, text, a space, a tab, a BOM (byte order mark), even a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

you can use...

```
header('Location: your_url.php');
```

or you also use

```
?>
<script> window.location="your_url.php" </script>   
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html');
```

But remember that it won't work if there's any output already sent by php script. If so, you will get warning (check your error_reporting and display_errors in php.ini). 
So, in other words, you can't put it after var_dump because var_dump produces output. It might be also a good idea to put exit() after var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

Use this PHP code header `('location:http://www.google.com')`

and this javascript code:

```
<script>
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com'   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = '';
    $password = '';
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.google.com/xx');
    $numbers = '8899';
    $message = 
    'hi check it
    !@#$%^&*
    ';
    $senderName = 'Winder';
    try {
    $response = $client->sendSMS($username, $password, $numbers, $message, $senderName)
    var_dump($response);
    } catch(SoapFault $exception ) {
    echo $exception->faultcode . ' : ' .$exception->faultstring . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
<?php
echo '<div style="text-align:center;padding-top:200px;">Go New Page</div>'; // Show Message
        $gourl='http://stackoverflow.com'; // goto url
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL='.$gourl.'">'; //   Content= Redirect time (seconds)
        exit;

?>
----------
```